# How to convert byte string to 16-bit images with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have many images written in byte form to a bin file that I need to read and reconstruct into images. I have no issue doing this with 8-bit images but 16-bit images are giving me an issue. Here is my code for handling 16-bit images:

```
    f = open(bin_path, "rb")  # contains all the bytes of my image
    batch = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16)
    num_images = len(batch) / (height * width)
    reconstructed_batch = batch.reshape(int(num_images), width, height)

    for pixData in reconstructed_batch:
        im = Image.fromarray(pixData.astype("uint16"))
```

The images that come back are the lower 8-bit data split from the upper 8-bit data.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mann.jpg)

Any idea how I can get it to work as a 16-bit image?

Comment: why use numpy? just read `height * width` bytes from the file and use that byte string to create an `Image`